# I wasn't able to update Windows Defender in 2 years

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, windows-update, windows-defender

In Windows 10, now 11, I have an update queued for Windows Defender.

```
Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.399.1620.0) - Current Channel (Broad)
```

This, or are least a similar one has been in that queue for at least 2 years and it always fails to install.

```
Install error - 0x80070643
```

I tried it all to get it to work. Clear the Update Cache, reset Update Service, disable Windows Defender, Repair it, and Reset it. I even tried to manually remove all its files, with safe boot and all, but the permissions are a nightmare and I can't delete the files. Even just the "Definition Updates" which I presume are corrupted. I also tried to disable all other anti-virus software and VPN, but the same issue. I also tried to install "Windows Defender", a seemingly standalone version of the anti-virus software, but it didn't affect the Windows integrated version.

I've been searching for that error message and update version on and off again for 2 years as well to fix this. I even updated to Windows 11 in an attempt to fix it. The only option I haven't tried yet it completely formatting the drive and re-installing Windows.

I have Malwarebytes running, so I'm not afraid of having viruses, but I know that Defender is a good security software and actually kinda want it to run in parallel.

And yes, Windows Defender actually isn't running. It's files haven't been updated in 2 years, and the Windows UI fails to find a running Security Version/Engine, stating that the last update was 30/11/2021.

Any advice that I may haven't already tried?

[Edit] Update Logs (truncated download part due to character limit):

```
2023/11/01 15:11:19.9706104 30496 16588 Handler         * START *   Command Line Install  Updates to install = 1
2023/11/01 15:11:19.9709878 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : NotifyClient (26396)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Update progress, reboot status = unspecified
2023/11/01 15:11:19.9710286 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback to client with code Update progress and error 0 
2023/11/01 15:11:20.0260858 30496 16588 Test            AUTest.cab validation: Test keys are not allowed
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4743165 30496 16588 Handler         Command line install completed. Return code = 0x00000000, Result = Succeeded, Reboot required = false
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4744585 30496 16588 Handler         * END *   Command Line Install 0x0
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4745510 1784  8076  Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : NotifyClient (8076)(0) called for update id a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200, code = Update progress, percent complete = 33
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4745959 1784  30920 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback for inner update : E7E06682-ECBC-4633-A7A9-862D1CED3BAA.200, top-level update A15498A7-8912-4029-A9F7-3EDA39155C79.200, reboot required = unspecified, commit required = No, callback info length = 0
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4747118 1784  30920 DownloadManager CloseUpdateInstallDirectory invoked for Update ID = E7E06682-ECBC-4633-A7A9-862D1CED3BAA.200, serverID = 7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D, Update installation result = 0x00000000.
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4747545 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : NotifyClient (26396)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Update progress, reboot status = unspecified
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4747950 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback to client with code Update progress and error 0 
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4751240 1784  30920 DownloadManager CloseUpdateInstallDirectory successful for Update ID = E7E06682-ECBC-4633-A7A9-862D1CED3BAA.200.
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4751334 1784  30920 DownloadManager Unlock the sandbox of update E7E06682-ECBC-4633-A7A9-862D1CED3BAA.200 (session data: (null))
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4756171 1784  30920 DownloadManager Preparing update for install, updateId = 60598B0A-28FF-4C3A-8245-4B8998917F27.200.
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4756491 1784  30920 DownloadManager Lock the sandbox of update 60598B0A-28FF-4C3A-8245-4B8998917F27.200 (session data: (null))
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4765103 1784  30920 Misc            SusDeleteDirectoryW deleted directory=C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install
2023/11/01 15:11:20.4765116 1784  30920 DownloadManager Deleted install directory C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install
2023/11/01 15:11:20.6397579 1784  30920 Handler         *FAILED* [800700DE] file = C:\__w\1\s\src\Client\wutrust\lib\cabverify.cpp, line = 34
2023/11/01 15:11:20.6397599 1784  30920 Handler         *FAILED* [800700DE] file = C:\__w\1\s\src\Client\wutrust\lib\trust.cpp, line = 222
2023/11/01 15:11:20.8823232 1784  30920 DownloadManager ExtractUpdateFiles
2023/11/01 15:11:20.8823631 1784  30920 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : Update 60598b0a-28ff-4c3a-8245-4b8998917f27.200, Top-level update a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200 deployment data prepared successfully.
2023/11/01 15:11:20.8824425 30496 16588 Handler         CUHCmdLineHandler::put_Priority called with dhPriority=2
2023/11/01 15:11:20.8825222 30496 16588 Handler         * START *   Command Line Install  Updates to install = 1
2023/11/01 15:11:20.8828502 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : NotifyClient (26396)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Update progress, reboot status = unspecified
2023/11/01 15:11:20.8828904 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback to client with code Update progress and error 0 
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9191089 30496 16588 Handler         Command line install completed. Return code = 0x00000000, Result = Succeeded, Reboot required = false
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9192423 30496 16588 Handler         * END *   Command Line Install 0x0
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9193230 1784  30920 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback for inner update : 60598B0A-28FF-4C3A-8245-4B8998917F27.200, top-level update A15498A7-8912-4029-A9F7-3EDA39155C79.200, reboot required = unspecified, commit required = No, callback info length = 0
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9194329 1784  30920 DownloadManager CloseUpdateInstallDirectory invoked for Update ID = 60598B0A-28FF-4C3A-8245-4B8998917F27.200, serverID = 7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D, Update installation result = 0x00000000.
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9198001 1784  30920 DownloadManager CloseUpdateInstallDirectory successful for Update ID = 60598B0A-28FF-4C3A-8245-4B8998917F27.200.
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9198077 1784  30920 DownloadManager Unlock the sandbox of update 60598B0A-28FF-4C3A-8245-4B8998917F27.200 (session data: (null))
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9199936 1784  30280 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : NotifyClient (30280)(0) called for update id a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200, code = Update progress, percent complete = 66
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9202085 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : NotifyClient (26396)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Update progress, reboot status = unspecified
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9202678 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback to client with code Update progress and error 0 
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9203253 1784  30920 DownloadManager Preparing update for install, updateId = 8CD4F80A-244F-4D9F-B99C-A9CF3E0B9A68.200.
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9203553 1784  30920 DownloadManager Lock the sandbox of update 8CD4F80A-244F-4D9F-B99C-A9CF3E0B9A68.200 (session data: (null))
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9261399 1784  30920 Misc            SusDeleteDirectoryW deleted directory=C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9261412 1784  30920 DownloadManager Deleted install directory C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9420537 1784  30920 Handler         *FAILED* [800700DE] file = C:\__w\1\s\src\Client\wutrust\lib\cabverify.cpp, line = 34
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9420554 1784  30920 Handler         *FAILED* [800700DE] file = C:\__w\1\s\src\Client\wutrust\lib\trust.cpp, line = 222
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9646248 1784  30920 DownloadManager ExtractUpdateFiles
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9646752 1784  30920 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : Update 8cd4f80a-244f-4d9f-b99c-a9cf3e0b9a68.200, Top-level update a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200 deployment data prepared successfully.
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9647600 30496 16588 Handler         CUHCmdLineHandler::put_Priority called with dhPriority=2
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9648749 30496 16588 Handler         * START *   Command Line Install  Updates to install = 1
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9652447 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : NotifyClient (26396)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Update progress, reboot status = unspecified
2023/11/01 15:11:21.9652829 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback to client with code Update progress and error 0 
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0309753 30496 16588 Handler         Command line install completed. Return code = 0x80070714, Result = Failed, Reboot required = false
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0310846 1784  8976  Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : Update a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200 failure delegate invoked.
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0311052 30496 16588 Handler         * END *   Command Line Install 0x8024200b
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0311781 30496 16588 Handler         *FAILED* [8024200B] file = C:\__w\1\s\src\Client\Engine\handler\cmdline\lib\UHCmdLine.cpp, line = 1126
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0311792 30496 16588 Handler         *FAILED* [8024200B] file = C:\__w\1\s\src\Client\Engine\handler\cmdline\lib\UHCmdLine.cpp, line = 1090
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0311879 1784  2544  Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : NotifyClient (2544)(0) called for update id a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200, code = Update failed, percent complete = 100
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0312499 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : NotifyClient (26396)(0) called for update id A15498A7-8912-4029-A9F7-3EDA39155C79.200, code = Update failed, percent complete = 100
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0313027 1784  30920 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback for inner update : 8CD4F80A-244F-4D9F-B99C-A9CF3E0B9A68.200, top-level update A15498A7-8912-4029-A9F7-3EDA39155C79.200, reboot required = unspecified, commit required = No, callback info length = 0
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0313116 17080 30904 ComApi          Deployment callback complete for UpdateID = a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79, callback code = 8, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0314103 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : NotifyClient (26396)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Update failed, reboot status = unspecified
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0314457 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback to client with code Update failed and error 0 
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0314604 1784  30920 DownloadManager CloseUpdateInstallDirectory invoked for Update ID = 8CD4F80A-244F-4D9F-B99C-A9CF3E0B9A68.200, serverID = 7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D, Update installation result = 0x80070643.
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0315686 1784  30920 DownloadManager CloseUpdateInstallDirectory successful for Update ID = 8CD4F80A-244F-4D9F-B99C-A9CF3E0B9A68.200.
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0315803 1784  30920 DownloadManager Unlock the sandbox of update 8CD4F80A-244F-4D9F-B99C-A9CF3E0B9A68.200 (session data: (null))
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0318085 1784  30920 Deployment      *FAILED* [80070643] Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : Installing for Top level update id a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200, bundled update id 8cd4f80a-244f-4d9f-b99c-a9cf3e0b9a68.200 [CUpdateDeploymentJob::DeploySingleUpdateInternal:3158]
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0318110 1784  30920 Deployment      *FAILED* [8024200B] Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : Installing for Top level update id a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200, bundled update id 8cd4f80a-244f-4d9f-b99c-a9cf3e0b9a68.200 [CUpdateDeploymentJob::DeploySingleUpdateInternal:3177]
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0318147 1784  30920 Deployment      *FAILED* [8024200B] file = C:\__w\1\s\src\Client\UpdateDeployment\Lib\UpdateDeploymentJob.cpp, line = 3179
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0318251 1784  30920 Deployment      Mutex will be closed.  index = 0, HANDLE = 00000000000005FC
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0318309 1784  30920 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : Method failed for update a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200, hrDeploy = 0x8024200b
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0318321 1784  30920 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : Update a15498a7-8912-4029-a9f7-3eda39155c79.200 failure delegate invoked.
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0352128 1784  30920 Agent           AddEventGroup: Adding non-pending event for update id E7E06682-ECBC-4633-A7A9-862D1CED3BAA.200
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0352172 1784  30920 Agent           AddEventGroup: Adding non-pending event for update id 60598B0A-28FF-4C3A-8245-4B8998917F27.200
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0352220 1784  30920 Agent           AddEventGroup: Adding non-pending event for update id 8CD4F80A-244F-4D9F-B99C-A9CF3E0B9A68.200
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0352260 1784  30920 Agent           AddEventGroup: Adding non-pending event for update id A15498A7-8912-4029-A9F7-3EDA39155C79.200
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0356100 1784  30920 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : Job complete delegate invoked.
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0356131 1784  30920 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : Ending deployment for updates, CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator, Exit code = 0x00000000
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0356796 1784  25700 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : NotifyClient (25700)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Job complete, reboot status = no reboot
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0357251 1784  25224 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : WaitForEnd invoked for deployment job. Beginning the wait now!
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0357343 1784  25224 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : WaitForEnd for deployment job completed. Job state = Complete
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0357368 1784  25224 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : CallbackWorker returning successfully.
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0358367 1784  28144 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : WaitForEnd invoked for deployment job. Beginning the wait now!
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0358417 1784  28144 Deployment      Deployment job Id F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 : WaitForEnd for deployment job completed. Job state = Complete
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0358462 1784  28144 Agent           WU client deploy call id 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 final update deployment job F8C4ECAF-33D3-412C-BD43-F78EFA8D9857 result = 0x00000000.
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0358480 1784  28144 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Call complete delegate invoked.
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0358687 1784  28144 Agent           * END * execution of Deploy call id = 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69, CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0358877 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : NotifyClient (26396)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Call complete, reboot status = unspecified
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0359207 17080 30980 ComApi           Install ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0359224 17080 30980 ComApi          Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0359595 17080 30980 ComApi          Reboot required = False
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0359603 17080 30980 ComApi          Call error code = 0x80240022
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0359610 17080 30980 ComApi          * END *   Install ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0359760 1784  26396 Agent           Deploy call 25DBCADA-1E32-414D-B8EC-6499F28B4C69 : Callback to client with code Call complete and error 0 
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0360168 17080 26540 ComApi          Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0
2023/11/01 15:11:23.0360815 17080 26540 ComApi          * END *   All federated installs have completed. ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV = wpLfR4FgoUuQ8/zQ.4.1), hr = 0x00000000
```

Comment: Have you tried a in-place repair install of the same build you are running, Windows Defender not running, can of course be assigned of an malicious infection.

Comment: I tried Windows Reset, and updating to Window 11 if that's what you mean.

Comment: That is absolutely not what I mean, running the Windows 11 22H2 (presumably your not running 23H2) Setup.exe from within Windows, will perform an in-place repair install.

Comment: Where would one find that setup.exe? I find media creation tools, isos, and installation assistants, but no simple setup.exe.

Comment: The Windows 11 22H2 ISO.

Comment: Just did such an install, and the issue persists.

Comment: So the upgrade was performed successfully and didn’t simply rollback due to an error?

Comment: Yes, I had to re-apply other updates, while previously it was all up to date, with the exception of the topical issue.

Comment: You should probably provide the respective WindowsUpdate.log, after you attempt to install the Windows Defender update, in order to eliminate the chance the log contains anything helpful. Beyond that I would try [clearing the signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/846842/updating-windows-defender-antivirus-fails-with-err) you do have installed in the event the reason Windows Defender cannot start is due to file corruption.